# Is there any reason to align more strongly than cache lines?

Tags: performance, memory, memory-management, memory-alignment

Does it help performance to align objects to page boundaries? I know aligning to cache lines helps performance, but is there any benefit to stronger alignments, in any circumstances?

I know that if data is swapped to disk, page boundaries might be nice. Is there anything else to consider?

EDIT: I am only interested in full scale computers, such as desktops, laptops, and servers. Any examples of how requiring alignment stronger than that of cache lines could be helpful would be much appreciated.

Comment: Certainly. There is a plethora of computer systems and I/O devices in out there, each one with peculiar quirks and requirements. DMA controllers are frequently some of the worst offenders out there, especially on oddball embedded devices. Of course alignment may also have a cost beyond the wasted space due to cache line collisions, so such micro-optimization needs to be handled with care and a deep knowledge of the target hardware.

Comment: @doynax, thanks for the response. I failed to mention that I am interested in full scale computers, such as desktops, laptops, and servers. I know that is still very broad, but I was hoping to get some examples of how alignment stricter than cache line might be helpful in such situations.

Comment: Generally speaking time an I/O device or driver with a larger block size than the cache line is directly mapped into memory you have the opportunity to gain performance through judicious alignment. On desktop PCs and servers this most often includes memory mapped file I/O, such as through virtual memory paging, as well as memory shared with GPUs and performance networking interfaces. For an explicit example see `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` on Win32.

Comment: So it sounds like it comes into play when working with hardware outside the internal state of the program? Like, a program that basically performs a computation in a vacumm would probably not worry about stricter alignments, but you'd consider it in some cases when working with specific hardware.

Comment: Yes, for the most part, though crossing page boundaries isn't entirely free either and some nasty addressing bit-hacks have been known to take advantage of specific alignments. Actually excessive alignment widths tend create cache line conflicts and _hurt_ performance.

Comment: OK, that clears up what I was looking for, If you want to copy and paste your comments to an answer I'd select it.